# How to point to index.html with Java built-in Web Server?

Tags: java, webserver

I have a very simple Java Web Server (following [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1040097/Create-a-Simple-Web-Server-in-Java-HTTP-Server)), is there a way to point to the index.html file (coming from the Bootstrap) in handler instead of hard-coding the response?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;

public class SO {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int port = 9000;
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
        System.out.println("server started at " + port);
        server.createContext("/", new RootHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    }

    public static class RootHandler implements HttpHandler {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
            String response = "<h1>Static Response</h1>";
            he.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: pointing to the index.html is not possible because there are no pointers in Java :)

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to serve the content of a local index.html file as the response body?

Comment: Exactly, I'd like to display content of index.html as a response body

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in HttpServer is very low-level and, AFAIK, doesn't provide this feature. But nothing prevents you from reading the file and sending its content to the response output stream:

```
File file = new File("index.html");
he.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
try (OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody()) {
    Files.copy(file.toPath(), os);
}
```

Comment: Does this work once the project is packaged into a .jar?

Comment: This reads the index.html file from the file system. Whether the classes are in a jar or not doesn't matter. If the index.html is not on the file system but in the jar, it's not a file anymore, but a classpath resource, that must be read using the class loader.